# Is it fundamentally possible pass a binary buffer to VRAM with WebGL?

Tags: node.js, webgl

This is an odd question, but let's say I have a large buffer of binary data in Node.js that I want to process with [headless WebGL](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl). I've worked with textures in the past in WebGL, but I cant seem to find any way to support actual raw binary data buffers in Node.js being worked on by WebGL. Is it fundamentally possible? Does the capability exist at all?

If the answer is no, would [extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Using_Extensions) change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

> [gl.bufferData(target, someArrayBufferView, storageHint)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferData)

or

> [gl.texImage2D(target, mipLevel, width, height, border,
> format, type, someArrayBufferView)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D)

?

Both take a typed array of binary data. So do [`bufferSubData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferSubData) and [`texSubImage2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImageSub2D)

Comment: But I can't read raw binary data from a file to an array buffer, right? ArrayBuffer is different from Buffer, so it looks to me like to use an ArrayBuffer like normal, I'd have to do `fs.readFile('./myDirectoryContainingBinFiles/selectedFile.bin', function(err, data)
{
    terrainData = new Uint16Array(toArrayBuffer(data));
})` which with large 1-10GB files, we're talking about max buffer sizes, this would be an expensive operation no? The purpose of the GPU acceleration is to process 100s of GB fast, I think that conversion is going to take up a lot of time

Comment: An array buffer, rather than storing raw bytes of binary data like Buffer, will actually store unsigned16bit, 8bit, whatever ints. Which, actually converting to those ints is not a free process, so it's type conversion going on between bytes and ints. And I'm using some of that binary as 32 bit ints, floats, 16 bit ints, 64 bit ints, 5 char strings, etc, so I would then have to do a more expensive process to convert those 8bit ints into the various data types they're supposed to represent. Right?

Comment: A node `Buffer` is just another type of ArrayBuffer view. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays) no copy required. Just create the appropriate kind of view of the same Buffer data. `const u8 = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync('somefile).buf)`